# AMD Radeon turns black when using fullscreen

Tags: amdgpu, fullscreen

This is my setup

- Dell Xeon Workstation
- Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.3
- Kernel Version: 6.5.0-15-generic (64-bit)
- Graphics Platform: X11
- Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon RX 460 Graphics
- two identical LG HD displays.

When I use an application in full screen mode (e.g. VLC, Vivaldi, games,...) chances are high, that the display turns black as if it has received a suspend command.

Consequently, if the error disappears (either on its own or by closing the application), the power led of the display is flashing and the OSD shows "DVI-D", just as if the display was turned off and on again.

The error is not display-related, means it can happen on the right as well as on the left display, but only when an application goes to full screen mode.

The error is not 100% reproducible but I have not been able to identify any reliable dependencies that causes/prevent the error. But what I can say is, that I experienced this behavior also with Ubuntu 20.04 with exactly the same hardware.

I have found several posts that describe a similar error, but they all referred to NVIDIA cards, so this was not really helpful. I should add, that I am still quite new to Linux.

Does anybody know a solution or at least a direction in which I could further investigate? If needed, I can provide more information of course, but I need to know the corresponding commands (linux newbie).

**Update:**
As suggested by Daniel T, I unchecked "Allow applications to block compositing". For a couple of hours I thought that this might be the solution as everything seemed fine. But then the error happened again. But I'd like to report two observations:

1. During the last test, both displays had an application running in full screen (VLC on the left, Vivaldi on the right) but the error occurred only on one of the screens, while the other was happily working. In this case it was the one with VLC, but as written above, the error is independent of the display and the application.
2. After unchecking that option, I had the feeling (!) of an increased stability. As the error is not really reproducible, I am careful with that statement, but I wanted to mention it anyway.

Comment: Does disabling direct scanout (idk which config or the name for Ubuntu) fix the problem?

Comment: I don't know. I've never heard of that before. By what I've read so far, i do not have the feeling that this is the problem but I will try to investigate further in this direction. Anyway, your comment made me to add more system details to my question.

Comment: What if you uncheck "Allow applications to block compositing" in compositor in display & monitor in KDE system settings?

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, I have updated my op to report the results.

Comment: I have a same issue of Asus A9-9420, the screen blacks out if I run video full screen for 70+ seconds,  but I can still hear the audio for 10+ seconds, then my computer restarts.

Comment: I know by downscaling the resolution will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might fixed this program by download one of the drivers from this website https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers (some drivers does not work for me) and run `amdgpu-install` to build the `amdgpu-dkms`.

I also upgraded kernel to 6.5 version beforehand and now it seems to be working fine in the fullscreen mode.

Comment: Some drivers won't build and throws error on amdgpu-dkms. Then you can purge it and try other drivers.